# I've Installed Inkscape via "apt-get install" in LXTerminal but I cant find where is it?

Tags: lubuntu

I'm new to Lubuntu, I was using ubuntu with unity for 1 year and I haven't faced such a case ! Please help me :( !

Comment: Are you sure it was installed? Try running `inkscape` in a terminal. Normally it should be placed in a submenu named "Graphics" in your main menu.

Comment: maybe useful for the future: the quickest way of finding a program is `run` (alt-f2), start typing and suggestions will appear; also, Synapse is a good replacement of the Dash program of Unity (http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/11/synapse-gnome-do-launcher-app-review-ubuntu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you installed with the Terminal aka `sudo apt-get install inkscape`, the program is located in the LXDE Menu>Graphics category.

Comment: "If you installed with the Terminal" - it doesn't really matter *how* it was installed, afaik.

Comment: Of course not, but noting that he can't find the Menu itself, well..